# How to read in a .cfg.txt file

Tags: c++, xcode, sfml

I've been trying to read this file for some time now and tried about everything I could think of. I placed the file in my Products folder and In my resource folder and included (ResourcePath + "File.cfg.txt") and neither worked. I'd appreciate it if someone could tell me what I'm missing and where to put this file to read it in. Again I'm using Xcode and the SFML library with it.

Keys.cfg.txt

Window_close 0:0

Fullscreen_toggle 5:89

Move 9:0 24:38

/////////////////////////////////////////

.CPP

```
#include "EventManager.h"
using namespace std;

EventManager::EventManager(): m_hasFocus(true){ LoadBindings(); }

EventManager::~EventManager(){
    for (auto &itr : m_bindings){
        delete itr.second;
        itr.second = nullptr;
    }
}

bool EventManager::AddBinding(Binding *l_binding){
    if (m_bindings.find(l_binding->m_name) != m_bindings.end())
        return false;

    return m_bindings.emplace(l_binding->m_name, l_binding).second;
}

bool EventManager::RemoveBinding(std::string l_name){
    auto itr = m_bindings.find(l_name);
    if (itr == m_bindings.end()){ return false; }
    delete itr->second;
    m_bindings.erase(itr);
    return true;
}

void EventManager::SetFocus(const bool& l_focus){ m_hasFocus = l_focus; }

void EventManager::HandleEvent(sf::Event& l_event){
    // Handling SFML events.
    for (auto &b_itr : m_bindings){
        Binding* bind = b_itr.second;
        for (auto &e_itr : bind->m_events){
            EventType sfmlEvent = (EventType)l_event.type;
            if (e_itr.first != sfmlEvent){ continue; }
            if (sfmlEvent == EventType::KeyDown || sfmlEvent == EventType::KeyUp){
                if (e_itr.second.m_code == l_event.key.code){
                    // Matching event/keystroke.
                    // Increase count.
                    if (bind->m_details.m_keyCode != -1){
                        bind->m_details.m_keyCode = e_itr.second.m_code;
                    }
                    ++(bind->c);
                    break;
                }
            } else if (sfmlEvent == EventType::MButtonDown || sfmlEvent == EventType::MButtonUp){
                if (e_itr.second.m_code == l_event.mouseButton.button){
                    // Matching event/keystroke.
                    // Increase count.
                    bind->m_details.m_mouse.x = l_event.mouseButton.x;
                    bind->m_details.m_mouse.y = l_event.mouseButton.y;
                    if (bind->m_details.m_keyCode != -1){
                        bind->m_details.m_keyCode = e_itr.second.m_code;
                    }
                    ++(bind->c);
                    break;
                }
            } else {
                // No need for additional checking.
                if (sfmlEvent == EventType::MouseWheel){
                    bind->m_details.m_mouseWheelDelta = l_event.mouseWheel.delta;
                } else if (sfmlEvent == EventType::WindowResized){
                    bind->m_details.m_size.x = l_event.size.width;
                    bind->m_details.m_size.y = l_event.size.height;
                } else if (sfmlEvent == EventType::TextEntered){
                    bind->m_details.m_textEntered = l_event.text.unicode;
                }
                ++(bind->c);
            }
        }
    }
}

void EventManager::Update(){
    if (!m_hasFocus){ return; }
    for (auto &b_itr : m_bindings){
        Binding* bind = b_itr.second;
        for (auto &e_itr : bind->m_events){
            switch (e_itr.first){
            case(EventType::Keyboard) :
                if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Key(e_itr.second.m_code))){
                    if (bind->m_details.m_keyCode != -1){
                        bind->m_details.m_keyCode = e_itr.second.m_code;
                    }
                    ++(bind->c);
                }
            break;
            case(EventType::Mouse) :
                if (sf::Mouse::isButtonPressed(sf::Mouse::Button(e_itr.second.m_code))){
                    if (bind->m_details.m_keyCode != -1){
                        bind->m_details.m_keyCode = e_itr.second.m_code;
                    }
                    ++(bind->c);
                }
            break;
            case(EventType::Joystick) :
                // Up for expansion.
                break;
            default:
                    break;
            }
        }

        if (bind->m_events.size() == bind->c){
            auto callItr = m_callbacks.find(bind->m_name);
            if(callItr != m_callbacks.end()){
                callItr->second(&bind->m_details);
            }
        }
        bind->c = 0;
        bind->m_details.Clear();
    }
}

void EventManager::LoadBindings(){
    std::string delimiter = ":";

    std::ifstream bindings;
    bindings.open("keys.cfg");
    if (!bindings.is_open()){ std::cout << "! Failed loading keys.cfg." << std::endl; return; }
    std::string line;
    while (std::getline(bindings, line)){
        std::stringstream keystream(line);
        std::string callbackName;
        keystream >> callbackName;
        Binding* bind = new Binding(callbackName);
        while (!keystream.eof()){
            std::string keyval;
            keystream >> keyval;
            int start = 0;
            int end = keyval.find(delimiter);
            if (end == std::string::npos){ delete bind; bind = nullptr; break; }
            EventType type = EventType(stoi(keyval.substr(start, end - start)));
            int code = stoi(keyval.substr(end + delimiter.length(),
                keyval.find(delimiter, end + delimiter.length())));
            EventInfo eventInfo;
            eventInfo.m_code = code;

            bind->BindEvent(type, eventInfo);
        }

        if (!AddBinding(bind)){ delete bind; }
        bind = nullptr;
    }
    bindings.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have to copy the respective files in the bundle, and that only objective-c can provide you the full name of the file on the destination device.

To overcome this, make a `.mm`-file and place a c++ trampoline function in there, which gives you the full path (see code below).

One pitfall can be that you have to make sure that the config- and text files like `"keys.cfg"` are actually copied into the bundle. Select the respective file in the project and open the property inspector; make sure that - the respective target in "Target Membership" is checked.

```cpp
// File: myFileNameProvider.mm
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#include <iostream>

std::string GetTextureFilename(const char *name)
{
    NSString *nameAsNSString = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:name];
    NSString *fullName = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
                          pathForResource:nameAsNSString ofType: nil];
    if (fullName)
        return std::string([fullName UTF8String]);
    else
        return "";
}
```

Then, in your CPP-code, declare the signature of `std::string GetTextureFilename(const char *name)`, and before opening the file get the full path by calling it:

```
// MyCPPFile.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

// declaration:
std::string GetTextureFilename(const char *name);

void myC_Func {
        std::string fullPath = GetTextureFilename("keys.cfg");
        std::ifstream bindings;
        bindings.open(fullPath.c_str());
        if (!bindings.is_open()) {
            std::cout << "! Failed loading keys.cfg." << std::endl;
        }
        ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you I will do exactly that